# somene got access to my sensitive information accidentally published on github

Tags: github

I accidentally published my production application on a public github repo
just an hour after that someone forked it

I don't know what to do the repo contained all the application credentials and a months of coding he also forked some other repositories

I removed the repo but fork is now public

Is there anyway to remove it?

Comment: Rather than try and remove the repo (who knows how many local copies there are?) you need to **revoke the credentials**.

Comment: Have you contacted the person who forked the repo and requested that they remove it? Either way you should immediately change/revoke any private credentials that were leaked.

Comment: storing credentials or private keys in any kind of repo is highly irresponsible. There are bots who are searching for this kind of data in github and bitbucket to stole them. For example to mine bitcoins on server which credentials become available. The only choice is to revoke all security items: passwords, private keys, serial nubers, … .

Comment: I'm afraid if I contact him he know the value of the repo

Comment: Contact GitHub support for additional options.